# using nested lists/nested loops

Tags: python, list, nested

I'm trying to figure out how to use nested lists/nested loops in Python. I'm supposed to write function(s) to create a new table that is comprised of adding the indices of 2 inputted tables in the form of lists. So, for example, if the function was addTables, I would run:

```
addTables([[1,1],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,2]])
```

and I would get:

```
[[3,3],[3,3]]
```

I'm having trouble figuring it out. First, the function I wrote returns 
[3,3,3,3] when I run my code:

```
def addElements(element1,element2):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(0,len(element1)):
        for j in range(0,len(element1[i])):
            new_element = element1[i][j] + element2[i][j]
            newlist.append(new_element)
    return newlist
```

Second, we're supposed to use multiple functions. I can't figure out how to split up the program so that different parts are completed by different functions. Could someone point me in the right direction? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `import numpy as np; print(np.add([[1,1],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,2]]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First using nested `for` loops

```
def addTables(first, second):
    new_table = []
    for i in range(len(first)):
        new_list = []
        for j in range(len(first[0])):
            new_list.append(first[i][j] + second[i][j])
        new_table.append(new_list)
    return new_table

>>> addTables([[1,1],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,2]])
[[3, 3], [3, 3]]
```

Another way to do this would be to break it up into two functions. The first can add two lists, then the outer function can call that to add tables.

```
def addLists(first, second):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(first)):
        new_list.append(first[i] + second[i])
    return new_list

def addTables(first, second):
    new_table = []
    for i in range(len(first)):
        new_table.append(addLists(first[i], second[i]))
    return new_table

>>> addTables([[1,1],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,2]])
[[3, 3], [3, 3]]
```

More concisely, this can be done using nested list comprehensions

```
def addTables(first, second):
    return [[i+j for i,j in zip(a, b)] for a, b in zip(first, second)]

>>> addTables([[1,1],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,2]])
[[3, 3], [3, 3]]
```

Lastly you can use `numpy` in the future, which will perform linear algebra very efficiently

```
import numpy as np

def addTables(first, second):
    return np.array(first) + np.array(second)

>>> addTables([[1,1],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,2]])
array([[3, 3],
       [3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not initialising the inner lists. To do that, you need to append a new row at the start of the outer loop body. However, there is a much easier way. Behold the power of the standard library:

```
[[a+b for a,b in zip(arow, brow)] for arow, brow in zip(element1, element2)]
```

What `zip` does is to pair up the elements in two or more iterables, such as your lists. The other 'trick' is to use a list comprehension to build the new table.

Comment: That's cool, but can you generalise your method to any size of matrix? Like, with any number of rows.

Comment: Try it and get back to me ;)

Comment: The reason that there are two levels of nesting is the same reason you usually have two nested loops for a 2D array. As long as you don't make it a 3D or 4D array, you should be fine.

Comment: Oh yeah, I actually just got confused by your notation of `arow` and `brow`, I think ^^ But totally makes sense now that I put my thinking caps on

Comment: Good. Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you want to return a nested list but you're only creating and appending results to a simple list. So basically your code should look something like

```
def addElements(element1,element2):
    global_result = []
    for i in range(len(element1)):
        # For each line, create a lower level list
        row_result = []
        for j in range(len(element1[i])):
            new_element = element1[i][j] + element2[i][j]
            row_result.append(new_element) # Add element to your low-level list
        # After the loop on the columns, add the row result to your global list
        global_result.append(row_result)
    return global_result
```

As to making that into multiple functions, I'm not too sure either...